# How do I combine stacks of items in follower inventory?

Tags: planet-explorers

In Planet Explorers (PC, Steam), I've given my follower some ammo (arrows). Every time I transfer a batch of ammo to her, it appears as a separate stack in her inventory. If I take the ammo back, it appears in separate stacks in my inventory.

My inventory has a "split" button at the bottom to split stacks ... but how do I combine stacks? These are all identical wooden arrows.

[image: Follower's inventory, showing three stacks of ammo]

In my own inventory, if I click the 'sort' button, any stacks will be combined during the re-sorting process. However sorting inventory means I lose my own manual organization, so it's not a process I'd like to rely on.

Comment: Have you tried combination of controls? Maybe shift or ctrl while using mouse click

Comment: Yep. Tried Ctrl, shift, alt, and combos of these.